# Lifting the question ban

Tags: discussion, support, question-answer-ban

I joined the site 8 months ago and had to face a question ban as I was not aware of the policies of site( At present only two of my 4 questions are having a negative downvote).

The site policy says that my ban will be automatically lifted if my positive contributions outweigh the negative votes which according to me had done.

Also my last question was posted in month of May and site's policy says that I can ask a question after 6 months of my latest question which I am still not able to do as I get same message *We are no longer accepting questions from this account*

What should I do so that I can ask that one question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> At present only two of my 4 questions are having a negative downvote
>
> The site policy says that my ban will be automatically lifted if my positive contributions outweigh the negative votes which according to me had done.

That's not the full story. You have 8 more deleted questions, 6 of which have negative votes. Some of those were deleted by you and some were deleted by [automatic processes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). The system takes all of these into account, too.

> Also my last question was posted in month of May and site's policy says that I can ask a question after 6 months of my latest question

It turns out your [last question was posted in August](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/155833). As far as I can tell, you have never been question-banned for six months. Between June 2021 and now, you posted 4 more questions (all of which were since deleted): [#1](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/155833), [#2](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/155473), [#3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/152904), [#4](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/152875)

> What should I do so that I can ask that one question?

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: Ah I got the problem, The august question that you are talking about was asked from my different profile ( which I created specifically for some other site) and merged it with my existing profile a month ago.